# How to get and store multiple genrated edittext value in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, dictionary, dynamic

I am adding multiple Edittext at the click of button. I am also getting the value of these Edittext, but I am unable to store data in array.

```
EditText textIn;
Button buttonAdd, buttonShow;
LinearLayout container;
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    buttonShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show);
    container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            EditText editText1 = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText editText2 = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            allEds.add(editText1);
            allEds.add(editText2);
            Button buttonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                }
            });

            container.addView(addView);
        }
    });

    buttonShow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

            for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                Log.e("My data", strings[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here I am getting all value using **strings[i]**, but I want to store value in array like this. ***[{"Name": "Smith","Age", "26"},{"Name": "Jhon","Age", "30"}]***. Here I will get Smith,26 and Jhon, 30 from multiple generated Edittext. Array will be extended after generating more dynamic fields. 
Please help me.

Comment: you want it as Json string `[{"Name": "Smith","Age": 26}]`? or Elements in Array with key Name,Age with value Smith and 26?

Answer (score 0):

You say you have to get it as an array.  As I see it,  you're already getting it as a **String** array.  What else do you want?  The way you're describing the expected result looks like a half-baked json output.  Perhaps you can create a class that represents the **Person** whose info you want and then create an **ArrayList** of the **Person** type.  Also to make things easier to stuff in the **Person** object you can declare a constructor that takes **name** and **age** as parameter. In your loop you can create a **Person** object using that constructor and then add that object to the **ArrayList**.
This would help :

```
class Person{
        String name;
        int age;
        Person(String name, int age){
            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;
        }
    }
```

Then before going into your loop,  declare an ArrayList of type Person

```
ArrayList<Person>persons=new ArrayList<Person>();
```

And finally in your loop :

```
Person temp = new Person(*get the name, get the age*);
```

persons.add(temp);

And voila!,  you have your person ArrayList ready.